# React_native: How to remove underline from TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

Here is my code:

```
<TextInput borderBottomColor='#ffffff'
style={{flex:1, color:'#000000', fontSize:20, marginLeft:1, marginRight:5, paddingTop:1 }}></TextInput>
```

Currently ,it is showing border line below EditText and also showing underline while entering input

I want to remove both border line and underline in text.
Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think in your cases it happen in Android.. 
you can just add transparent attribute in underlineColorAndroid.

```js
underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
```

That will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
is there any way to show underline on iOS also?

Comment: I dont think there is any pre-defined on how to show underline on iOS but you can try to manipulate the bottomBorderColor and add some styling to it